# Finding upper or lower limits given one of the limits and the solution using Python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, integral

I would like to calculate the lower bound of an integral, given the f(x), the upper bound and a given solution.

or

the upper bound of an integral, given the f(x), the lower bound and a given solution using python.

How do I do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

This will work if a) the integral is known for your integrand when there are symbolic limits and b) the resulting equation can be solved:

```
from sympy import integrate
from sympy.abc import x, u
f = x + 3
lo = u
hi = 10
eq = integrate(f, (x, lo, hi))
eq, solve(eq, lo)
```

That gives

```
(-u**2/2 - 3*u + 80, [-16, 10])
```

But if you define `f = exp(x) + 1/x` you will end up with an equation that SymPy cannot solve with `solve`, but `nsolve` will work. (If you end up with an expression containing and Integral then you might need to use bisection by repeatedly plugging in a specific value for the unknown limit and numerically evaluate the integral until you get the desired result.)

If you want the integral to equal a certain value, `v`, then `solve(eq - v, u)` where `u` is the symbol that was used for the unknown limit.

Comment: Thanks bro, but what I am asking is, suppose I have a solution, say 3.4. and the following:

3.4 = integral of f(X), lower = 0. upper = b; I want to find b such that integrating f(x) from 0 to b will give me the result 3.4.

Comment: Bro I am getting a complex number for the lower limit. Any idea why? my equation contains sympy.gamma and sympy.exp

Comment: Is there also a real solution? Please post the equation that you are solving.