# Finding upper or lower limits given one of the limits and the solution (area under the curve) on a discrete point "curve"

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, integral

I have an x vs y data. I made the non-linear estimation of that data and the resulting function looks like the below:
[image]
and the estimated function is: 25342*^9 −155900^8+409218^7 − 599317^6 + 537190^5 − 303116*^4 + ... + 274

I used [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61324165/15428146) suggestion to find the upper limit of my integral by using the below code:

```py
p_optimal = estimate_function_from_data_points()
```

```py
from sympy import integrate, solve
from sympy.abc import x, u
f = 25342.695344882944*x**9 - 155900.56387247072*x**8 + 409218.9290579793*x**7 - 599317.5264117827*x**6 + 537190.6784517929*x**5 - 303116.0648042093*x**4 + 105493.81468203208*x**3 - 20422.11374996729*x**2 + 1263.9293528900394*x + 274.55521542679185
lower = 0.0925 # Initial
upper = u
eq = integrate(f, (x, lower, upper))
eq, solve(eq + 100, u)

Out: [-0.114399781774514 - 0.112912224139529*I,
 -0.114399781774514 + 0.112912224139529*I,
 0.145632609024802 - 0.532284754794354*I,
 0.145632609024802 + 0.532284754794354*I,
 0.646926125977188 - 0.679233975801008*I,
 0.646926125977188 + 0.679233975801008*I,
 1.20499184950745 - 0.534200757552949*I,
 1.20499184950745 + 0.534200757552949*I,
 1.53445822404458 - 0.201823934360761*I,
 1.53445822404458 + 0.201823934360761*I]
```

I get 9 results (as expected because it's 9th order function) and all of them are complex numbers because I don't have a nice function as given on the answer. What methods can I use to get a real number solution?

Edit: When I run the below code, I get 100 as a result of the integral. So, the upper limit should be around 0.945

```py
lower = 0.0925 # Initial 
upper = 0.945
integrate(f, (x, lower, upper)).evalf()

Out: 100.016292426307
```

Comment: do you want to separate the imaginary part from the real part?

Comment: I can separate the imaginary part from the real part easily as I get results like: 0.1456 + 0.5323*i.  The other x-axis (the upper limit) is a real number that represents time in hour

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the question but it is unclear if complex solutions are what you expect. Furthermore, if the image you attached displays the function, wouldn't we expect the bounds to be around zero and ~1.2?

Comment: Maybe you should use SymPy's `real_roots` function instead of `solve`. I would post a demonstration but the code supplied in the question is incomplete and doesn't run.

Comment: @t.o.  Complex numbers can be part of the solution but there has to be a real number solution because my x-axis consists of real numbers (time data in seconds) and I need to have a real number solution to determine the upper limit to make sense in my use case.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I updated the code. Now runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for `eq` to be equal to 100 then you should ask to solve `Eq(eq, 100)` or `eq - 100` rather than `eq + 100` (since that's asking for `eq` to be equal to `-100`). With that:

```py
In [14]: solve(eq - 100, u)
Out[14]: 
[-0.212948010713551, 0.944530756107237, 0.0760056875453759 - 0.410894283883493⋅ⅈ, 0.076005687545375
9 + 0.410894283883493⋅ⅈ, 0.530254482189976 - 0.556134814597481⋅ⅈ, 0.530254482189976 + 0.55613481459
7481⋅ⅈ, 1.07772724094452 - 0.347706425047349⋅ⅈ, 1.07772724094452 + 0.347706425047349⋅ⅈ, 1.367830243
4028 - 0.115266894498628⋅ⅈ, 1.3678302434028 + 0.115266894498628⋅ⅈ]
```

Note that the first two roots are real (one negative and one positive).

You can ask solve to return only real or only positive roots by setting assumptions on `u`:

```
In [23]: u = symbols('u', positive=True)

In [24]: eq = integrate(f, (x, 0.0925, u))

In [25]: solve(eq - 100, u)
Out[25]: [0.944530756107237]
```

Here the equation you are solving is really numerical but you are using SymPy's `solve` function which is intended to find exact analytic solutions. Here are some faster ways to solve this using SymPy's `real_roots`, `nroots` and `nsolve` functions:

```
In [15]: [r.n(3) for r in real_roots(eq - 100)]
Out[15]: [-0.213, 0.945]

In [16]: nroots(eq - 100)
Out[16]: 
[-0.212948010713551, 0.944530756105865, 0.0760056875453764 - 0.410894283883493⋅ⅈ, 0.076005687545376
4 + 0.410894283883493⋅ⅈ, 0.530254482189946 - 0.556134814597486⋅ⅈ, 0.530254482189946 + 0.55613481459
7486⋅ⅈ, 1.07772724094385 - 0.34770642504758⋅ⅈ, 1.07772724094385 + 0.34770642504758⋅ⅈ, 1.36783024340
417 - 0.115266894502763⋅ⅈ, 1.36783024340417 + 0.115266894502763⋅ⅈ]

In [17]: nsolve(eq - 100, u, 0.9)
Out[17]: 0.944530756105865
```